# Hibernate DB2 ROW_NUMBER() error

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

Im having problems in Hibernate when I'm using the ROW_NUMBER() of DB2 it says QueryException: undefined alias: ROW_NUMBER. What to do? Thanks

```
String strQuery= " SELECT c_.name, c_.id, c_.description, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY     
                   c_.name) AS rownum FROM Category as c_ ";
Query query = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().
getCurrentSession().createQuery(strQuery);
```

Comment: How are you using calling it from hibernate. Please paste your code

Comment: to avoid this kind of discrepancies between databases hibernate has dialects.http://www.javabeat.net/qna/163-list-of-hibernate-sql-dialects/ For specific usage i would like to know exactly what your trying to do. for instance if youre intending to use rownumber for pagination there are specific methods to accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER()` is not a valid function in DB2, but it is in SQL Server.  You want the `rownumber()` function.  Change your query to the following, and it should work:

```
String strQuery= " SELECT c_.name, c_.id, c_.description, rownumber() OVER(ORDER BY     
               c_.name) AS rownum FROM Category as c_ ";
```

Comment: Wrong, ROW_NUMBER() is a function in DB2 

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0401kuznetsov/index.html